# Matching networks for two different impedances of input and output

Tags: impedance-matching, power-amplifier

I am designing a Doherty power amplifier. The load pull analysis to get the impedances from maximum gain and PAE are:

- \$ZS_{low}=R_1+jX_{s1}\$
- \$ZL_{low}=50 \Omega \$
- \$ZS_{sat}=R_2+jX_{s2}\$
- \$ZL_{sat}=25 \Omega \$

I need to match \$ZS_{low}\$ to \$ZL_{low}\$ when only the main amplifier is active and \$ZS_{sat}\$ to \$ZL_{sat}\$ when both amplifiers, main and p,eak are active. The bandwidth needed is 90 MHz, from 380 MHz to 470 MHz, and the S11 parameter must be less than -20 dB inside the BW.

In order to get the maximum transfer power, the condition of \$Z_S=Z_L^\ast\$.

Performing the matching networks independently is not a problem.  The problem is that only one matching network is needed for the two conditions.

How I can accomplish it, is it possible? What type of matching networks are used for this problem? PI and T networks don't solve the problem.  The LL multi-section doesn't either because S11 parameter is around -13  to 15 dB.

I can't find any papers about it, only if a center frequency is set instead of a bandwidth.

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't match independently and switch with an RF switch (or switches) when required ? This would most likely get you the exact matching to the required conditions. If you're chasing one, common matching solution for all the conditions mentioned, without any switching (for reasons of simplicity or cost I presume) then it sounds like you may need to compromise... That is, match to the best geometric mean match of the two different requirements ...

Comment: Yes, I think that a switch could be a solution, but at the moment, is not contemplated.